# Scrapy pyOpenSSL Windows 7x64

Tags: scrapy, pyopenssl

I have installed pyOpenSSL on x64 windows 7 machine.

But every time I try to access a 'https' website I get the error

```
HTTPS not supported: install pyopenssl library
```

If you traceback the error this is where it is coming from:

```
scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http.py", line 34, in _connect
            raise NotSupported("HTTPS not supported: install pyopenssl library")
```

I look up `http.py` and find this:

```
from scrapy import optional_features

ssl_supported = 'ssl' in optional_features
if ssl_supported:
    from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory
```

When I go look for optional_features to add the path of pyopenssl I cannot find it.

Where is the optional_features file?
The idea was to find the file and add the path.

Is this a right way to go about this?
Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:

I uninstalled pyOpenSSL and attempted to reinstall via

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

but keep coming up short.
The error log: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?4066d45d10e18a4f#AwpphSnXEhq7Sc9fi6yZdt6O9YEHnHYZl+2k2QgITjQ=

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try:
easy_install pyOpenSSL==0.15